# Vue3 running into error- accessing file with different casing

Tags: vue.js, path, casing

Newer developer and first time using Vue (without typescript- I know, I know. Also I'm normally a vite fan but thought I'd "try something new" for a little project). I'm on Mac, VSCode will let me launch it locally and everything seems to be loading correctly however I keep getting an problem: Already included file name '/**u**sers/username/**d**ocuments/website/src/components/contactinfo.vue.js' differs from file name '/**U**sers/username/**D**ocuments/website/src/components/contactinfo.vue.js' only in casing.

Even if I change the file path all the way up to users and modify the casing, it still throws and error and won't let me actually deploy.

I'd love to avoid making a whole new project or new components sos

Changing the file paths within the component and App.vue, resaving the components under new names. I figured that would fix it but it still says the same error as above.

Comment: Vue is browser lib, it doesn't deal with local paths. You have a problem with a specific project and it's unknown what went wrong on your side. It could be Vue CLI (which is not the same as Vue), or Vite, or else. You'll need https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem because others don't deal with this problem constantly with common setups